# Why is my parallelized Sieve of Eratosthenes finding a small amount of numbers that are not prime?

Tags: java, concurrency, primes

So i'm trying to implement a parallell version of the Sieve in Java. I'm pretty sure my algorithm is very close to working, it works well for finding all primes up to a small number, (n < 1000 ish) but when the number gets bigger, the sieve finds a small amount of non prime numbers.
An example run with n = 10000000, and the sieve finds 664627 supposed primes numbers, while the actual correct number of primes is 664579. So it marked 48 non-primes as primes. If anyone would be able to take a look at the code below and provide some pointers, that would be greatly appreciated. The code can be compiled and run with Javac Oblig3.java - > java Oblig3   where n is a positive integer and is the max value for n and i is a positive integer and the number of threads to be used.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

class Worker implements Runnable {
    int n;
int id;
int numOfThreads;
int elementsPerThread;
Oblig3 parent; 
int[] primesLessThanRoot;  
byte[] oddNumbers;
CyclicBarrier barrier;
ReentrantLock lock;

Worker(int n, int id, int numOfThreads, int[] primesLessThanRoot, Oblig3 parent, 
CyclicBarrier barrier,ReentrantLock lock) {
    this.n = n;
    this.id = id;
    this.numOfThreads = numOfThreads;
    this.primesLessThanRoot = primesLessThanRoot;
    this.elementsPerThread = (int) (primesLessThanRoot.length / numOfThreads);
    this.parent = parent;
    this.barrier = barrier;
    this.lock = lock;
}

private void mark(int num) {
    int bitIndex = (num % 16) / 2;
    int byteIndex = num / 16;
    parent.oddNumbers[byteIndex] |= (1 << bitIndex);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if(id==1){
        System.out.println(primesLessThanRoot.length + " " + numOfThreads);
    }
    int index = id; 
    while(index < primesLessThanRoot.length){
        int count = 3; 
        int currentNum = primesLessThanRoot[index] * count; 
        while(currentNum <= n){
            if(currentNum % 2 == 1){
                mark(currentNum);
                // System.out.println("ID: " + id + " marking:" + currentNum + "( " + 
primesLessThanRoot[index] + " * " + count + " )"); 
            }
            count += 2;
            currentNum = primesLessThanRoot[index] * count; 
        } 
        index += numOfThreads;
    } 
    try {
        barrier.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

public class Oblig3 {
int root, n, threads, numOfPrimes;
byte[] oddNumbers;
Long startTime;
Long endTime;
Long totalTime;

Oblig3(int n, int threads) {
    this.n = n;
    this.threads = threads;
    root = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    oddNumbers = new byte[(n / 16) + 1];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    int threads;
    try {
        n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        threads = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        if (threads > Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()) {
            System.out.println("More threads than available cores, setting threads to 
max available cores");
            threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        }
        Oblig3 oblig3 = new Oblig3(n, threads);
        oblig3.sieveParallell();
        int[] primes = oblig3.getPrimes();
        SieveOfEratosthenes soe = new SieveOfEratosthenes(n);
        Long soeStart = System.nanoTime();
        int[] soePrimes = soe.getPrimes();
        Long soeTotal = (System.nanoTime() - soeStart);
        System.out.println("Parallell time: " + oblig3.totalTime);
        System.out.println("Sequential time: " + soeTotal);
        System.out.println(primes.length);
        System.out.println(soePrimes.length); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(primes, soePrimes));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Invalid input");

    }
}

void sieveParallell() {
    CyclicBarrier barrier;
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    byte[] oddNumbers = new byte[(n / 16) + 1];
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    SieveOfEratosthenes soe = new SieveOfEratosthenes((int) Math.sqrt(n));
    int[] primesLessThanRoot = soe.getPrimes();
    if (primesLessThanRoot.length > threads) {
        barrier = new CyclicBarrier(threads + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
            Worker worker = new Worker(n, i + 1, threads, primesLessThanRoot, this, 
barrier, lock);
            Thread t = new Thread(worker);
            t.start();
        }
    } else {
        barrier = new CyclicBarrier(primesLessThanRoot.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < primesLessThanRoot.length - 1; i++) {
            Worker worker = new Worker(n, i + 1, threads, primesLessThanRoot, this, 
barrier, lock);
            Thread t = new Thread(worker);
            t.start();
        }
    }
    try {
        barrier.await();
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        totalTime = endTime - startTime;

    } catch (InterruptedException | BrokenBarrierException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

boolean isPrime(int num) {
    int bitIndex = (num % 16) / 2;
    int byteIndex = num / 16;
    return (oddNumbers[byteIndex] & (1 << bitIndex)) == 0;
}

int[] getPrimes() {
    if (n <= 1)
        return new int[0];
    return collectPrimes();
}

private int[] collectPrimes() {

    int start = (root % 2 == 0) ? root + 1 : root + 2;

    for (int i = start; i <= n; i += 2)
        if (isPrime(i))
            numOfPrimes++;

    int[] primesWith0 = new int[(int) (numOfPrimes * 1.2)];
    primesWith0[0] = 2;
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2)
        if (isPrime(i))
            primesWith0[j++] = i;
    int count = 0; 
    for(int num : primesWith0){
        if(num != 0){
            count ++; 
        }
    }
    int [] primes = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        primes[i] = primesWith0[i]; 
    } 
    return primes;
}

static void printPrimes(int[] primes) {
    for (int prime : primes)
        System.out.println(prime);
}

static boolean isEqual(int[] a, int[] b) {
    boolean status = true;
    if(a.length == b.length){
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            if(a[i] != b[i]){
                System.out.println(String.format("A[%d]: %d B[%d]: %d", i, a[i], i, 
b[i])); 
                status = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if(a.length > b.length){
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                if (a[i] != b[i]) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("A[%d]: %d B[%d]: %d", i, a[i], i, 
b[i]));
                    status = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if (a[i] != b[i]) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("A[%d]: %d B[%d]: %d", i, a[i], i, 
b[i]));
                    status = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return status;
}

}
```

Comment: So your `isPrime()` method is sometimes returning false positives, but can you explain why you think it should work?

Comment: Try testing your `isPrime()` method in a simple serial framework.  If it works, then the problem is with your parallelisation.  If it doesn't work then fix the error.

Comment: You are doing bit manipulations on a shared array without even trying to implement a thread safe operation. Of course, this can produce inconsistent results. Besides that, there’s just too much noise in that code. Compare with, e.g. `BitSet primes = new BitSet(n); primes.set(2, n); for(int i = 2; i > 0 && i < n>>1; i = primes.nextSetBit(i+1)) for(int j = i + i; j < n; j += i) primes.clear(j);` which does the job in a few milliseconds, even without further optimizations. Can be queried like `numPrimes = primes.cardinality()` or `primes.stream().toArray()` when you need an array.